# Vim - swap columns with visual mode

Tags: vim, copy-paste, paste, cut

I have a markdown table like this.
I want to swap head3 column with head2.

```
| head1 | head3 | head2 |
|-------|-------|-------|
| foo   | baa   | none  |
| some  | text  | here  |
```

I can easily cut the column using visual mode (Ctrl-V), but how can I paste the column 'column-wisely'?

Also, which operating is easiert:

1. cut 'head 3' and paste behind 'head2'
2. cut 'head 2' and paste before 'head3'?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

When you've selected and cut something with <kbd>Ctrl+V</kbd>, Vim will paste it as a column too. You can <kbd>Ctrl+V</kbd> select the column you want to swap into and paste, and the column you just replaced will now be in your paste register. Go back to the column you cut first and paste one more time to move the replaced column.

In steps:

- Use <kbd>Ctrl+V</kbd> to select the entire `head3` column
- <kbd>x</kbd> to cut
- Use <kbd>Ctrl+V</kbd> again to select the entire `head2` column
- <kbd>p</kbd> to paste
- Move back to where `head3` used to be
- <kbd>p</kbd> to paste

[image: Column swap demo]

Comment: Sorry, this does not work. The result is a total mess.
Also why do I need to paste twice?

Comment: If your columns are next to each other, you can get away with only pasting once, but in the general case, you'll need to paste each column in its new position. Maybe this gif will help demonstrate.

Comment: My bad. I had nevom aliased to vim and with `neovim` this does not work. It does however work fine with vim. Thanks for the gif!!!

Comment: That's sort of surprising for Neovim; this seems pretty basic. Good to know!

Answer (score 1):

1. Move to the first pip `|` : `f+|` then to the character right after it by `l`
2. Start selecting the column: `Ctrl+v`
3. Move to the end of the file: `G`
4. Move to the second pip, the one after the header3: `2f+|`
5. Cut the selection: `d`
6. Move to the end of the line: `$`
7. And finally paste: `p`

[image]

> Also, which operating is easiert:
>
> 1. cut 'head 3' and paste behind 'head2'
> 2. cut 'head 2' and paste before
>      'head3'?

For me, both work the same way.